# Should i prioritise Prayer or Health?

Tags: salat

I am in a state of Janabah so I can't pray. To pray I will have to take Ghusl. But I am sick so if pray my sickness will increase. Should I pray or not  ? Should I bath or Not?  Should choose Prayer or Health  ?

Comment: Prayer is obligatory there is no situation where you should not pray. Depending on the nature of the sickness and the risks involved you could be required to do ghusl anyways, or have an alternative such as tayyamum.

Answer (score 1):

Salam
You can still pray by performing the tayammum, if you are unable to do ghusl. There are not one but two verses in the Qur'an about this:

1. O you who have believed, when you rise to [perform] prayer, wash your faces and your forearms to the elbows and wipe over your heads and wash your feet to the ankles. And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves. But if you are **ill** or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and do not find water, **then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and hands with it**. Allah does not intend to make difficulty for you, but He intends to purify you and complete His favour upon you that you may be grateful. (Qur'an 5:6)
2. O you who have believed, do not approach prayer while you are intoxicated until you know what you are saying or in a state of janabah, except those passing through [a place of prayer], until you have washed [your whole body]. And if you are **ill** or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and find no water, **then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and your hands [with it]**. Indeed, Allah is ever Pardoning and Forgiving.

Hope it helped. Please give an upvote if it did
JazakumAllah khayr

Answer (score 1):

Salam
There are already the right citations in the previous answer. Keep in mind that ghusl is a symbolic action. Purity before Allah means essentially to clean the heart from bad feelings and clear the head to be fully present when you pray. So do the symbolics as far as you are able to do so being aware of what it stands for.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't take bath Islam prescribes to do tayammum. You can check it in the internet. Salah five times is obligatory for every grownup and conscious Muslim whatever the situation is. Leaving Salah is major sin Islam. May Allah give you knowledge.